# Stationary point vs extreme points vs critical points

Tags: calculus

I am little bit confused about the terminology here. Adam Calculus and Thomas calculus define these in different ways.

In Adam Calculus :
[image]
In Thomas Calculus book:
[image]
**Critical points:** are points in which the derivative is zero or not defined

**Stationary points:** are points that the derivative is zero .

How we will define the **extreme points** ?

What we call  the global maximum points  and global minimum points ? Critical , or extreme points? Are the endpoints also critical points?

In the function below,is the points $x=1$ and $x=3$ critical points?

**Is there any universal agreement one the  definition of these terminologies?**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You're using "extreme point" to refer to an extremum.

A local extremum is a local minimum or maximum. A global extremum is a global minimum or maximum. Without a qualifier, what is meant is generally the global one.

For any function, an extremum always lies on some critical point (which include "endpoints" of intervals as well).
Stationary points are a subset of critical points.